# Keep attributes after Instance on Points Node in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Is there anyway to keep attributes when using Instance on Points?

[image]

Comment: So when reading the attribute of any instance, in this case you want to read `123`?

Comment: To expand on Markus' question: the logic behind your setup seems to be to give all instances on points the attribute `123`? It does not work like that, because even when you convert the cube to an instance before instancing on points, the output are new instances (instances of an instance), this is not just a pass-through of an instance. And if you want all new instances to get the value `123`, you just have to put the _Store Named Attribute_ node after the _Instance on Points_ node. But since you did not do that, obviously you want something else and your question needs clarification.

Comment: Explaining the real use case scenario may help. I have run into some similar situations in the past, but I don't want to potentially suggest an incorrect description of the problem, worrying OP could misunderstand, confirm my explanation fits, and then later on it would turn out it actually doesn't.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann en Markus, thx, I can continue on this not earlier then next week, hence the silence. I think I now how to approach it. In short what I want is to have tiles that can be made with the same shape tiles that are smaller. I thnk I can do this by storing data for each point in the pointcloud (which iteraton t is, which shape etc.).
I might delete the OP later.